# How do you apply colormanagement settings to EXR files?

Tags: color-management, .exr

How do you apply colormanagement settings to EXR files? 
When i do some color adjustment by using colormanagement and try to save exr file and open it in photoshop it looks like colormanagement settings was not applied to it.

Answer (score 6):

Correct.

Due to a very unfortunate design decision, no matter whatever your view transforms are set to, the EXR will *always* be the unadjusted, scene referred values from the Cycles render buffer.

In order to perform colour transforms from an OCIO configuration, you would need to perform this task externally using a tool such as ocioconvert from the OCIO package.

Note that while an EXR can contain any type of data, with regards to imagery and visual energy, it is a standard convention to store that data with linear visual energy ratios. That is, in terms of colour space transforms, you would want to avoid storing nonlinear encodings in an EXR file via baking in a transfer function curve.

Comment: Hi Troy, thanks for the answer! 

If my understanding is correct and if i want to combine blender passes in photoshop i can do it correctly only by using exr files?
I would really like to use your Filmic colormanagement, but i dont know how to apply it correctly to my photoshop pass based workflow.

Comment: Photoshop would be an exceptionally tricky bit of software to achieve this in as it is display referred by design. Photoshop is, ironically, entirely sub-optimal to do proper photographic manipulations in the scene referred domain with. About the best you can do is save out a 16 bit TIFF with the contrast curve look you like and go from there. Sorry.